# Xamarin.Forms iOS Maps MapClicked event called before PinClicked event

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I'm using Xamarin.Forms.Maps and want to handle click events and UI creation of the info windows on my way.
Android is working fine, but iOS makes me headache.

When creating the map, I assign the MapClicked event to a method

```
CurrentMap.MapClicked += MapIsClicked;
```

In this method some data is fetched, pins are added to the map and the PinClicked event is assign to a method.

```
CurrentMap.Pins.Clear(); <- I want to clear all pins, to see just the new pins
ListOfStations = --some database stuff--;
foreach (GasStationSmall station in ListOfStations)
        {
            Task.Run(() => AddMarker(station));
        }
```

AddMarker method:

```
CustomPin pin = new CustomPin()
        {
            ...
        };
        pin.MarkerClicked += PinClicked;
        CurrentMap.Pins.Add(pin);
```

All this works fine on Android. When clicked on a pin, the PinClicked event is raise without any problems. But iOS had the bad habbit, that it calls the MapClicked event before the PinClicked event. So the pins are cleared in the MapClicked method and the PinClicked event can't be raised because the pin is deleted.
So I've tried to do not clearing the pins when using iOS. Then the PinClicked event is called but after some map-clicks, the map is filled with pins.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Why you don't hold all the pins in an object, and try to delete them one by one by yourself instead clearing all of them using .Clear(). In this case, you don't delete the latest pin.

Comment: Also, with manual clear, you don't need to add all ListOfStations again with each MapClicked. Imagine if the list is big, it takes time. You also don't need to load ListOfStations from DB every MapClicked if you are sure the data will not be changed.

Comment: Deleting the pins one by one has the same effect.

Comment: It is hard to know why until I see the whole code. Can you tell me why you you assign PinClicked inside MapIsClicked while you don't get any fresh data from the map. You say some data is fetched, like what?